# Is There a Lint Rule to Enforce android:screenOrientation Values?

Tags: android, android-lint

I am working on a project where the client wants all activities locked to portrait orientation. The project is using a multi-activity architecture, so from time to time we add new activities to the manifest. And, on occasion, an activity gets added where the `android:screenOrientation` attribute is not added to the `<activity>` element. And, since `android:screenOrientation` is not listed for `<application>`, I do not see a way to set up an app-wide default.

Is there an existing Lint rule that can be used to detect missing `android:screenOrientation` attributes?

Comment: Does this help https://github.com/googlesamples/android-custom-lint-rules

Comment: @MuratKaragöz: That repo does not have any real Lint rules, only limited samples if you want to try writing your own. Thanks, though!

Comment: This [repo](https://github.com/alexjlockwood/android-lint-checks-demo) contains real examples. Also in the google repo there is a [ManifestDetector](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/refs/heads/master/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks/ManifestDetector.java) that could help.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti: I am trying to avoid writing a Lint rule, though that's certainly a possibility. I was hoping that there might already be one in the Android SDK that just needed to be enabled or something. Thanks for the resources!

Comment: If you DO end up finding a solution, even if you write a custom lint rule, it might be worth adding it as an answer, I'd definitely be interested in seeing it, for one :)